# Calculating Integral via Hermite

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Using the "First Hermite Approach" I have to calculate:

$$\int \dfrac{x^3+x^2+x}{x^4+2x^2+1} \mathrm dx $$

I really have no idea how to use this so-called First-Hermite-Approach. I wanted to solve this problem by using partial-fraction.. however, I'm not 'allowed' to?!

Thank you very much :)

---

EDIT:

In my book it says:

With P(x) and Q(x) being two Polynoms with deg P < deg Q, let
$
Q(x) = (x-a_1)^{k_1} \cdots (x-a_r)^{k_r} \cdot (x^2+2p_{1}x+q_{1})^{m_1} \cdots (x^2+2p_{s}x+q_{s})^{m_s} $

$ z(x) = (x-a_1) \cdots (x-a_r) \cdot (x^2+2p_{1}x+q_{1}) \cdots (x^2+2p_{s}x +q_{s})$

$ V(x) = \frac{Q(x)}{z(x)}.$

Then:
$\int \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx = \frac{U(x)}{V(x)} + \int \frac{w(x)}{z(x)} dx $ is the first-Hermite.

Well, that's it!

Comment: Unlucky, mate..

Comment: @K.L.: What book is this? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: The lecture notes (for university course) :) So not really "a book".

Comment: What is U(x), w(x)?

Answer (score 0):

Write the integral like $c\displaystyle\int \frac{f'}{f}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure which can avoid partial fraction:

$\int\dfrac{x^3+x^2+x}{x^4+2x^2+1}dx=\int\dfrac{x^3+x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx+\int\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$

Let $x=\tan\theta$ ,

Then $dx=\sec^2\theta~d\theta$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{x^3+x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx+\int\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{x^2+1}{2(x^2+1)^2}d(x^2)+\int\dfrac{\tan^2\theta\sec^2\theta}{(\tan^2\theta+1)^2}d\theta$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{2(x^2+1)}d(x^2+1)+\int\dfrac{\tan^2\theta\sec^2\theta}{\sec^4\theta}d\theta$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{2(x^2+1)}d(x^2+1)+\int\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{2(x^2+1)}d(x^2+1)+\int\sin^2\theta~d\theta$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{2(x^2+1)}d(x^2+1)+\int\dfrac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}d\theta$

$=\dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}+\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\dfrac{\sin2\theta}{4}+C$

$=\dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}+\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\dfrac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2}+C$

$=\dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}+\dfrac{\tan^{-1}x}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2(x^2+1)}+C$